# How do i prevent the following dotted rectangle from being rendered around my html5 video?

Tags: html, video

I did:

> ffmpeg2theora --aspect 4:3 -F 16 --optimize -x 320 -y 240 -o
>   video/Amy.ogv video/Amy.mp4

My file has:

```
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls poster="video/tn/Amy.jpg">
<source src="video/Amy.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
Your browser does not support the 'video' HTML5 tag.
</video>
```

[image: dotted bars] 
I get an annoying dotted bar - why? How do i eliminate it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the common issue of browsers identifying anything that can be 'clicked' in a particular way, dotted line here, to improve accessibility.

If this is this common problem you can use CSS to remove the outline:

```
a:active {outline: none;}
```

See links here:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/remove-dotted-link-borders/

Its worth looking at this note from a WEB accessibility project also for some thoughts around this also (essentially they point out it is there for a purpose):

- http://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/

Comment: I don't know why the negative, this is the right answer. Just need to change `a:active {outline: none;}` for `video {outline:none;}` and it's done